# struggling to get a simple BDD test suite for an API using gherkin apickli

Tags: node.js, cucumber, gherkin, web-api-testing

I'm trying to learn how to create a simple working step-definition file for my gherkin feature file using the nodejs apickli module. If I try to do a really simple proof of concept connecting to the GitHub API. Here is the API call using curl.

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/marktyers/orgs
```

This returns a response code of 200.

I have installed `cucumber` and `apickli`:

```
npm install --save-dev cucumber apickli
```

Here is my file structure:

```
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── test
  └── features
    ├── step_definitions
    │   └── myapi.js
    └── test.feature
```

Here is my `test.feature` file:

```
Feature:
  As a novice I want to test my BDD framework.

  Scenario: Retrieving an empty list should return a 200 code.
    Given I set Content-Type header to application-json
    When I GET https://api.github.com/users/marktyers/orgs
    Then response code should be 200
```

Here is my `myapi.js` file.

```
'use strict'

const apickli = require('apickli')

module.exports = function() {
  // cleanup before every scenario
  this.Before(function(scenario, callback) {
    this.apickli = new apickli.Apickli('http', 'httpbin.org')
    callback()
})
```

When I run the feature test I get:

```
Feature:

  As a novice I want to test my BDD framework.

  Scenario: Retrieving an empty list should return a 200 code.
  ? Given I set Content-Type header to application-json
  ? When I GET https://api.github.com/users/marktyers/orgs
  ? Then response code should be 200

Warnings:

  1) Scenario: Retrieving an empty list should return a 200 code. - test/features/todo.feature:5
    Step: Given I set Content-Type header to application-json - test/features/todo.feature:6
   Message:
     Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

   Given('I set Content-Type header to application-json', function (callback) {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     callback(null, 'pending');
   });

2) Scenario: Retrieving an empty list should return a 200 code. - test/features/todo.feature:5
  Step: When I GET https://api.github.com/users/marktyers/orgs - test/features/todo.feature:7
 Message:
   Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

   When('I GET https://api.github.com/users/marktyers/orgs', function (callback) {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     callback(null, 'pending');
   });

3) Scenario: Retrieving an empty list should return a 200 code. - test/features/todo.feature:5
 Step: Then response code should be 200 - test/features/todo.feature:8
 Message:
   Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

   Then('response code should be {int}', function (int, callback) {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     callback(null, 'pending');
   });

1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (3 undefined)
0m00.000s
```

I know I need to include additional step definitions but where should they go and what should go in them?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely installed the latest version of cucumber-js 2.x instead of 1.x

The step definitions in apickli are implemented in the old version and won't be picked up if you have the latest version 2.x of cucumber-js.

npm install -g cucumber-js@1.3.3 should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Is there any documentation for the latest version please?

Comment: Nope sorry unfortunately it's quite hard to find any solid documentation on the latest release for either. I only found out about cucumberjs from their release documentation and for apickli it doesn't mention it's only compatible with cucumber@1.x, the only giveaway is the way the steps are implemented. Just something we need to get used to in the JS/Node land as opposed to Java etc., everything is just so poorly documented...